# Entering the UK as a visitor, 5 years after tier 4 visa was curtailed

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa

I am hoping someone can assist me, as I am unsure of what to do in this situation: I was a student in the UK 5 years ago. I rushed into the decision of studying abroad and chose a course that was unsuitable for me. I also had anxiety issues that I was dealing with. Anyway, I had poor attendance and wasn't performing well academically. The university I was at informed that they were going to revoke their sponsorship. I received the curtailment letter shortly thereafter, and I left the UK immediately (I did not overstay the curtailed visa). I enrolled at a university in my home country, I graduated, and now have a full time job.

In 2016, I acquired a new citizenship that allows me to enter the UK as a visitor visa-free. I am planning on going to the UK in 
mid-October 2018 using my newly acquired citizenship for 10 days to visit my brother who's currently undertaking his masters degree there. Will I face problems at immigration when I try to enter?

I'll be bringing important documents with me (return home ticket, proof of employment, hotel reservation...etc). Will that be enough or do I need to take further steps?

Comment: Will you be travelling on the passport of the country you were a citizen of when you were a student in the UK?  If not, they probably won't even know you are the same person.  Did you overstay your student visa, or did leave before its (curtailed) validity expired?  If you didn't overstay, that's an important point.  Finally, where (roughly) are your new and old citizenships?  Immigration officials are much less likely to worry about a citizen of (say) Australia overstaying than a citizen of (say) Somalia.

Comment: Note: My comment was not intended to answer, but as a request for information (and an indication of why I wanted that information).  Please [edit] your question to include the answers.

Comment: @MartinBonner Thank you for your input! To answer your questions:

1- No I will not be traveling on the same passport I used when I was a student 5 years ago, I will be traveling using the passport I recently acquired which allows me to enter the UK as a visitor visa free.
2- No I did not overstay my visa, I left the UK immediately after receiving my letter of curtailment. 
3- my original citizenship is middle eastern, and the one which I acquired recently is Caribbean.

Comment: @MartinBonner: were they not taking biometrics 5 years ago? I know the US did further back than that.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, congratulations on recovering from what must have been a nasty set-back.

I don't think being kicked out of University and immediately leaving the UK is likely to adversely affect your entry to the UK:  firstly you actually complied with your visa conditions, and secondly they are unlikely to connect you to the curtailed visa (unless there is a question about it on the entry form - **do not lie in your answers there**.)

Of course, there is nothing to stop the UK Border Agency being difficult just on general principles, but I don't think you will have any *more* difficulty than anyone else from your new country.